# How to maintain tables when we have multiple customers having single product?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

What tables and relationships should I design for an app supporting multiple customers?

I am developing a web application which has multiple customers and a single product. I want daily sales data to be stored for each customer - there are about 10 customers.

My application has a screen where the following data is entered and saved:

1. Customer Name
2. Price per quantity
3. Quantity
4. Total amount
5. Amount
6. Balance
7. Old Balance
8. Total Balance

I need to decide how to create tables, the number of tables and the relationships between them. For example, should I have separate tables for each customer? I need the total sales to be maintained in database.

Comment: You should really only NEED 2 tables, a customer table with the information above as columns, then a product table that lists your products. you can give your products product ID's so that the two tables can link together.. you can just then run simple sum formulas to get totals from the customer table, or create a view to link the two tables and do all the summing for you....

Comment: i have to store customers daily sales and i am having only one product and i think i don't need product id????

Comment: I have reformatted your question a little, to make it more readable. Please [edit] it further with more clarification if you feel it can be improved further.

Comment: @MohammedNadeem Sure, but for scale-ability if you ever want to add more products that could easily be accommodated then. if you design this and ad-hoc the products into the db there will be significant scale-ability issues down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two tables. One customer main table with columns Id,Name

Id can be of identity type which increments for every insert of customer name.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30)
)
```

Second table can be sales table as there is a single product , you can just have that as a column in this table. Columns for this table would be

1. id(Again identity primary key for sales table)
2. Product name
3. Quantity
4. Total amount
5. Amount
6. Balance
7. Old Balance
8. Total Balance
9. CustomerId (foreign key referencing the customer table)

Also sales date can be added to the sales table, which will be helpful to retrieve sales based on date.

While retrieving, you can use the relationship between the tables to get the customer name.
Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thank you :-) Can you please mark my answer as right answer ?